# Shade where a function f lies below a function g

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

I have two functions:

```
f[x_] = 2 Cos[x]
g[x_] = -Sqrt[3]
```

I find the points of intersection.

```
sol = Solve[f[x] == g[x] && -2 Pi <= x <= 4 Pi, x]
pts = {x, f[x]} /. sol
```

I plot the two curves, the points, then I want to plot where the graph of f lies below the graph of g. I can fill the area between the curves:

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 4 Pi},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]
   }]
```

But how can I fill the area between the curves only where the graph of f lies below the graph of g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
 Filling -> 1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, White}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is this one of those methods that is still undocumented?

Comment: No, it is in the documentation under the Details section of Filling (last entry in the first table you encounter there).

Comment: @SjoercC.deVries Got it. Thanks for the reference.